# Prove that absolute value of complex conjugate is equal to complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've tried to prove that $ |\overline z| = z$, where z is a complex number: $$ z = a + bi$$ I always end with: $$ |\overline z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$ Colud you help me to prove it?

Thanks

Comment: Can't prove what isn't true.  And as $|\overline z|$ is real and $z$ needn't be, that isn't true.

Comment: I don't think the downvotes are fair.  Kacper had a question, asked it clearly, and showed work and explained and explicitly showed where s/he keep having a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean $|\overline z|=|z|$, which is clearly true since $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\sqrt{a^2+(-b)^2}$, as you have found. $|\overline z|\neq z$ unless $z$ is real; the left-hand side is a real number, while the right-hand side is complex.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you must mean ${|\bar{z}|=|z|}$, since ${|\bar{z}|=z}$ wouldn't make sense (${|\bar{z}|}$ is always going to give you a strictly real number, and so it can't be equal to $z$ since $z$ is some complex number that needn't have non-zero imaginary part).

You have actually proved it. Remember the definition of ${|z|}$. If ${z=a+bi}$ then

$${|z|=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$$

We also know that ${|\bar{z}|=|a-bi|=\sqrt{a^2 + (-b)^2}}$. But, as you know,

$${(-b)^2 = b^2}$$

And so overall

$${|\bar{z}|=\sqrt{a^2 + (-b)^2}=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = |z|}$$

As required!

Comment: Thank you, all right! So it looks that in Rudin's book (polish version, 2012) "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" is a misprint ;D

Comment: @Kacper yeah it's a misprint :)